# “If this, and if that.” With or without Comma?

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma

> I’ll appreciate it if you wash the car, and if you take out the trash.

Should I use a comma before *and*, or not?

Comment: Put a comma there if you hear one. But first, remember that the idiom is _I'll appreciate **it** if ..._. Unless you mean that you will increase in value if these chores are done.

Comment: It sounds rather strange as it stands. I think most people would use 'I’ll appreciate it if you wash the car and take out the trash.' In other words, it's probably a polite request for you to do your chores (not opt to do one) rather than the statement of a scale of approval.

Comment: And if it's not related to chores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best form of words is what Edwin Ashworth suggested, and no comma is needed if you opt for that. But if you leave the wording as it stands, then it needs a slight pause between the two parts of the sentence, because the second part comes across as an afterthought. In which case, leave the comma in. Having it in or out doesn't affect the grammar, but it does affect the way the sentence is heard.

Comment: What I said applies to any sentence, whatever it's about. "I’ll appreciate it if you wash the car, and if you take out the trash." The fact that you've repeated the "if you" from the first half of the sentence implies a slight break between the two halves, as if the second half was an afterthought - "if you wash the car...oh, and if you take out the trash". But if you re-write it without the repeated "if you", it comes across as one uninterrupted thought - "if you wash the car and take out the trash". Then it needs no comma. It's a question of sound, you see, not of grammar or subject matter.

Comment: +1 for the "afterthought" part.  I can only imagine someone adding "and if you take out the trash" like that in dialogue, or perhaps in writing if they wanted to make it seem like the second request was an afterthought.  If that's the intention here, the comma should stay there.  Otherwise, if this were, say, an e-mail, I agree with Edwin.